# Axios Get not resolving

Tags: node.js, async-await, axios

I'm trying to make a simple `GET` request with `axios` that follows the redirect until network idle, but I can't get the promise to resolve.  It seems to work for most urls, but not the below url, specifically - not sure if there's an issue with my code or something peculiar to this one redirect (others of similar format work fine, ie with different `mid=XXXX` parameters.

A `GET` request (with no headers or authorization) redirects fine in Postman, but `axios` won't return anything.

```
async function axiosGet() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://www.awin1.com/awclick.php?mid=4802");
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Running this I only get back back my bash prompt with nothing logged.  Assigning my `axiosGet()` function to a variable, and then logging that variable only yields `Promise { <pending> }`.  Just looking to get a resolved promise object, good to go from there.

Comment: console.log does not need `await `....axiosGet will return a new Promise if you are getting from this method you should call like this: `await axiosGet`

Comment: Thanks - have removed the ```await``` before ```console.log(response)```.  But wrapping ```axiosGet()``` in another async function, and calling ```await axiosGet();``` gives the same result (a pending Promise).

Comment: `console.log(response)` print a pending Promise?

Comment: Sorry, no, if I call ```axiosGet()``` or call function ```async function myFunction() { await axiosGet(); }``` (followed by function call ```myFunction();```) it doesn't do anything at all (just back to bash prompt).  If, for example. in another async function I ```let myVar = await axiosGet(); console.log(myVar);``` the result logged is ```Promise { <pending> }```.

Comment: Issue seems to be to do with ```axios``` handling of 302 (or other?) redirects, and if there is a redirect loop it doesn't seem to throw an error.  Have refactored to use ```urllib``` instead, which throws an error object I can work with, but seems like the unsatisfactory answer.